# Copiar arquivo base de dados em uso em delphi

Tags: delphi

Utilizo o banco de dados Absolute Data Base. Ele é um banco embarcado com recurso de múltipla conexão em rede.

Estou fazendo um sistema de backup para copiar o arquivo .abs gerado pelo banco. O problema é que como o arquivo está em uso, não consigo realizar a cópia. Tenho que desconectar para realizar tal processo.

Existe alguma maneira de realizar essa cópia do arquivo em uso. Se o sistema tivesse em rede, todo os usuários logados deveriam estar desconectados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um aplicativo chamado Cobian Backup, diga-se de passagem que ele é gratuito. Nele existe uma opção que se chama copia de sombra. Habilitando ela você pode copiar o arquivo em uso.

A maioria dos aplicativos de backup possuem esta opção.

Não sei qual o seu caso, mas caso for fazer isto programaticamente terá que saber como utilizar o recurso de copia de sombra.

Segue link com exemplo de código: [Exemplo de código](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/misc4.htm)

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu já tenho e utilizo ele. Queria uma função para adicionar no meu sistema

Comment: @André, veja o link na resposta.

Comment: Para você, é inviável implementar um serviço de backup que fosse disparado durante a madrugada ? Digo isso, porque além do backup, as vezes pode ser necessário um Vacuum ou algo do tipo.(utilizamos PostgreSQL, e já tivemos o mesmo problema)

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma verificada. Não visto o link. Sobre disparar isso de madrugada para este sistema é inviável, pois em 85% dos casos, será usado em horário comercial em modo monousuário.